# Replace a string containing special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to replace a string that contains special characters. The purpose of this is to convert the query string into an understandable format for end users.

full string is:

```
var str = 'active=true^opened_by=6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441^ORassigned_to!=6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441^short_descriptionISNOTEMPTY^NQopened_atONToday@javascript:gs.beginningOfToday()@javascript:gs.endOfToday()^EQ';
```

Specifically the portion after `^NQ`, in this example: `opened_atONToday@javascript:gs.beginningOfToday()@javascript:gs.endOfToday()`. I have split the original string with `indexOf(^NQ)` and passing the resulting sub-strings to a function. I'm then trying a `.replace()` as below:

```
var today = replacementString.replace(/(ONToday@javascript:gs.beginningOfToday()@javascript:gs.endOfToday())/g, ' is today ');
replacementString = today;
```

I have tried with various combinations of the above line, but have not returned what I am hoping for.

I've had no issues replacing special characters, or strings without special characters, but the combination of the 2 is confusing/frustrating me.

Any suggestions or guidance would be appreciated

Comment: There's a good regex tester at https://regex101.com/

Comment: You need to escape [characters with special meaning in regex](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/Regular_expressions_1__Special_characters.html) by backslash to match those literally.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDavidBaker that was a really useful link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the `()` to `\(\)` to match it literally or else it would mean a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). For the match you could also omit the outer parenthesis and you have to escape the dot `\.` to match it literally.

[`ONToday@javascript:gs\.beginningOfToday\(\)@javascript:gs\.endOfToday\(\)`](https://regex101.com/r/uf21V0/1)

```js
var str = 'active=true^opened_by=6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441^ORassigned_to!=6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441^short_descriptionISNOTEMPTY^NQopened_atONToday@javascript:gs.beginningOfToday()@javascript:gs.endOfToday()^EQ';
var today = str.replace(/ONToday@javascript:gs\.beginningOfToday\(\)@javascript:gs\.endOfToday\(\)/g, ' is today ');
replacementString = today;
console.log(today);
```

Comment: That was exactly what was needed. I had tried with a backslash both sides of the braces e.g. '\(\\)\' which was obviously incorrect.